# Employing Pyspark ,determine the leading value and display it in a new column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
   Sl Now
    1   D
    2   D
    3   D
    4   R
    5   R
    6   C
    7   C
    8   C
    9   D
    10  P
    11  R
    12  R
    13  D
```

I have a dataset like above.

```
   Sl Now   lead
    1   D   R
    2   D   R
    3   D   R
    4   R   C
    5   R   C
    6   C   D
    7   C   D
    8   C   D
    9   D   P
    10  P   R
    11  R   D
    12  R   D
    13  D
```

I want to add a column called "lead" that will display the subsequent value of the "Now" column and will match the number of values in the 'Now' column. Can we carry this out with PySpark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

## Prep data

```py
a = "DDDRRCCCDPRRD"
a = list(zip(range(len(a)), a))
b = ["Sl","Now"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(a,b)
df.show()

+---+---+
| Sl|now|
+---+---+
|  0|  D|
|  1|  D|
|  2|  D|
|  3|  R|
|  4|  R|
|  5|  C|
|  6|  C|
|  7|  C|
|  8|  D|
|  9|  P|
| 10|  R|
| 11|  R|
| 12|  D|
+---+---+
```

## Imports

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W
```

## add an incremental ID

```py
df = df.withColumn("id", F.when(F.col("now") == F.lag("Now").over(W.orderBy("Sl")), 0).otherwise(1))
df = df.withColumn("id", F.sum("id").over(W.orderBy("Sl")))

df.show()
+---+---+---+
| Sl|now| id|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  D|  1|
|  1|  D|  1|
|  2|  D|  1|
|  3|  R|  2|
|  4|  R|  2|
|  5|  C|  3|
|  6|  C|  3|
|  7|  C|  3|
|  8|  D|  4|
|  9|  P|  5|
| 10|  R|  6|
| 11|  R|  6|
| 12|  D|  7|
+---+---+---+
```

## Get the lead value (method 1)

```py
df = df.withColumn("lead", F.collect_set("now").over(W.orderBy("id").rangeBetween(1, 1)))
df = df.select("Sl", "now", F.explode_outer("lead").alias("lead"))

df.show()
+---+---+----+
| Sl|now|lead|
+---+---+----+
|  0|  D|   R|
|  1|  D|   R|
|  2|  D|   R|
|  3|  R|   C|
|  4|  R|   C|
|  5|  C|   D|
|  6|  C|   D|
|  7|  C|   D|
|  8|  D|   P|
|  9|  P|   R|
| 10|  R|   D|
| 11|  R|   D|
| 12|  D|null|
+---+---+----+
```

## Get the lead value (method 2)

```py
df2 = df.select(F.col("now").alias("lead"), (F.col("id") - 1).alias("id")).distinct()
df1 = df.join(df2, how="left", on="id")
df1.select("Sl", "now", "lead").show()

+---+---+----+
| Sl|now|lead|
+---+---+----+
|  0|  D|   R|
|  1|  D|   R|
|  2|  D|   R|
|  3|  R|   C|
|  4|  R|   C|
|  5|  C|   D|
|  6|  C|   D|
|  7|  C|   D|
|  8|  D|   P|
|  9|  P|   R|
| 10|  R|   D|
| 11|  R|   D|
| 12|  D|null|
+---+---+----+
```